# Date sample code from apple website is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to figure out how ti use current date in Swift 3. I read Swift has moved NSDate to Date object. So I checked [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter) sample code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 410220000)

// US English Locale (en_US)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMMd") // set template after setting locale
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // December 31

// British English Locale (en_GB)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMMd") // // set template after setting locale
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // 31 December
```

But when I copy and paste this to my Xcode it is showing error that

```
Use of unresolved identifier DateFormatter
Use of unresolved identifier Date
```

When I check my swift version from terminal:

```
xcrun swift -version
Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Am I missing importing some libraries?

**EDIT**

If I change it to this

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 410220000)
```

It is working fine.

Comment: Where did you paste this code? It should go inside some method, of course. In answer to your question, the typical `import` statements (e.g. `import UIKit`) should include this.

Comment: of course it is inside a function.

Comment: Given your edit, your project must be configured for Swift 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have the latest Swift version installed on your computer, when  you check it in the terminal, but your project must be running on `Swift 2.3`.

Swift 2.3 does not know `DateFormatter` and `Date` types, it is only introduced in Swift 3.0+.

Comment: Yes I was using swift with code legacy assigned to "yes"